# EigenValue Factorisation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Ok this might sound a dumb and easy question here but I am literally lost with the basic algebra here, it's a part of my eigenvalue question and I just got stuck on this part. Can somebody please help me factorising this equation?

$$λ^3 + 3λ - 6$$

So I have to solve this further just couple of steps and find the eigenvalues, any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The expression you have only has one real root and two complex roots, thus is not factorable using rational numbers.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3+%2B+3x+-+6

If the question is asking you to find the <strike>eigenvectors</strike> eigenvalues and the underlying field is $\mathbb{R}$, you have encountered the problem with the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is not algebraically closed.

Comment: the question is to find the eigenvalues not vectors. I might have done some mistake in factorisation. Here's what my matrix was:

[ λ    -2   -1 ]
[-2    λ    -2 ]
[-1   -1     λ ]

After finding the determinants i got this solution:
λ ( λ^2 - 2 ) + 2 ( - 2λ - 2 ) -1 ( 2 + λ)
on further factorising I got the solution that I posted where I got stuck.

Comment: Finding the eigenvalues does not affect the fact that this polynomial's roots are not contained in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/factor-calculator/x%5E%7B%203%7D-7x-6/?origin=suggestion

Comment: the equation you gave is $x^3 - 3x + 6$